# php codeigniter, use getElementsByTagName('script'), how to include php code in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, getelementsbytagname

I use getElementsByTagName('script') and ('body'),('meta')... to get html and reassemble web pages.

for example:
the views.php:

```
<body>
  this is body
</body>

<script>
    var global_var = new Object(); 
    global_var.img_source='<?php echo $global_var['img_source']?>';
</script>
```

the con.php:

```
class Con extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->global_var['img_source']='test';
   }


   public function assemble(){
      $html=$this->load->view(views.php,'',TRUE);
      @$doc->loadHTML($html);
      $getdom_type=$doc->getElementsByTagName('script');
      $l=$getdom_type->length;

      for($i=0;$i<$l;$i++){
        $d=$d.''.$doc->saveHTML($getdom_type->item($i));
      } 
      $data['article_content']=$d; 
      $data['global_var']=$this->global_var;
      $this->load->vars($data);
      $this->load->view('index/article');
   }
}
```

the article.php:

```
<?php echo $article_content;?>
```

---

have error find in

```
// global_var.img_source='
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered
<p>Severity: Notice
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: global_var
.
.
.
```

This javascript and php code can not be obtained :

```
    <?php echo $global_var['img_source']?>';
    </script>
```

complete code:

```
global_var.img_source='<?php echo $global_var['img_source']?>';
```

Comment: Where do you define an Object in PHP named global_var?

Comment: set in public function __construct()